# First buy or sell of bitcoins

Tags: firstbits

What steps do I have to take to buy/sell bitcoins? What's the minimum amount of bitcoins that I can buy, and how much will I pay for transaction in a buy/sell operation?

Answer (score 1):

For a start and to get to know the different exchanges and wallets you should checkout: https://www.bestbitcoinexchange.io/ (I'm not affiliated with that website).

To buy and sell Bitcoin I recommend https://gemini.com and [https://xcoins.io](https://xcoins.io/?r=6377u7). https://coinbase.com is popular but I'm not a huge fan of them for a number of reasons.

Just sign up and add your bank account to purchase Bitcoin. Gemini allows you to buy/sell Ethereum as well.

If you're worried about adding your bank account I would use [https://xcoins.io](https://xcoins.io/?r=6377u7) or https://localbitcoins.com